# Laravel: Parse JSON object with array of "sub-objects" to model instance

Tags: json, laravel

In my (Laravel) application receive a JSON which looks like:

```
{
  "name": "order 1",
  "customer": "cus123",
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "amount": 1,
      "name": "cola",
      "price": "2.10"
    },
    {
      "amount": 3,
      "name": "fanta",
      "price": "2.00"
    },
  ]
}
```

I have create 2 models in Laravel, one `Order` and one `OrderItem`. I want to parse the received JSON to one `Order` instance `$order`.
I can get this done so by doing this in my `OrderController`:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request) {
    $order = new Order();
    $order->forceFill($request->toArray());
  }
}
```

It's possible to access properties now like `$order->name` and `$order->customer` in the `store` function of the controller. When i access the `$order->orderItems` i receive an array with "orderItems`but as array, not as instance of`OrderItem`.

I want that `$order->orderItems` returns an array of `OrderItem` instances. I tried the following in `Order` but this does not work as `'orderItems'` is not a `OrderItem::class` but is an array with multiple "OrderItems".

```
  protected $casts = [
    'orderItems' => OrderItem::class,
  ];
```

How can i achieve that `$order->orderItems` returns an array of `OrderItem` instances?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: dont forget to validate all request coming from your user, never trust your user, including your self when related to altering your database ^_^

Comment: Im not sure what you trying to achieve but I see 2 issue. 1. You cannot cast a non-exisiting attribute in your model, 2. Casting is converting a model attribute into a common data type, you cannot pass random things in there https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the following to your controller

- validation
- manual storing your Order
- manual storing each of your order items

.

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request) 
  {
    $your_rules = [
       'name' => 'required|string',
       'customer' => 'required|string', // related to customer id ?
       'orderItems' => 'array',
       'orderItems.*.name' => 'string',
       'orderItems.*.amount' => 'integer|gte:1',
       'orderItems.*.price' => 'numeric|between:0,99.99',
    ];

    $validated = $request->validate($your_rules);
    $order = Order::create([
       'name' => $validated['name'],
       'customer' => $validated['customer'], // is this customer id or name ?
    ]);

    // I assume you already declare relationship to OrderItem inside your Order model
    foreach ($validated['orderItems'] as $orderItem) {
        // this array only is optional
        $orderItem = Arr::only($orderItem, ['name', 'amount', 'price');

        $order->orderItems()->save($orderItem);
    }

    // reload saved order items
    $order->load('orderItems');

    dd($order);
  }
}
```

You can also create multiple children in single command.

```
$order->orderItems()->saveMany([
    new OrderItem(['name' => '...', ... ]),
    new OrderItem(['name' => '...', ... ]),
]);
```

Read here for more info https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

You can move this into your model as extra custom method.
For example:

```
public function saveOrderItems(array $orderItems): void
{
   $this->orderItems()->saveMany($orderItems);
}
```

And you call it as `$order->saveOrderItems($orderItems);`

P.S.

Dont forget to declare relationship in Order model.

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

Comment: I know about validation etc. but this was not relevant for the question, thanks anyway, i will implement it like that! I also use `$fillable =` ;-). I could have come to your solution my self, stupid.. But i wonder there is no way to do this with one command ? I mean parsing JSON to objects is such a common thing i cant imagine that there is no easier way to do it.

Comment: you can add all of your logic into service class and call it from your controller, that will be a single command , right ^_^.  ... anyway if you do only create order, that would be a single create command, problem is with the relationship ... for one extra command you can use `->saveMany` .. i will update my answer with this method

Comment: i forgot to add validation on orderItems as array and its content , you can set 'amount', 'name' and 'price' as required

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confuse with the whole Model relationship. Checkout the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), you need to define proper relationship and foreign key between your Order and OrderItem model.

Then your model should be like this;

```
//Order.php
class Order extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'customer',
    ];

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
    
}

//OrderItem.php
class OrderItem extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'amount',
        'name',
        'price'
    ];

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
    
}
```

Then your store method

```
public function store( Request $request ) {

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'customer' => 'required|exists:customers_table,id',
        'orderItems' => 'required|array'
    ]);

    $order = Order::create( $request->except('orderItems') );

    $items = $order->items()->createMany( $request->input('orderItems') );
}
```